# Парсинг JSON в C#

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

пытаюсь спарсить JSON так:

```
    public class buttonInfo
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string securityKey { get; set; }
        public string buttonID { get; set; }
        public IList<string> onlyFor { get; set; }
    }
    public class getAdminPanelJSON //Ответ от сервера getAdminPanelJSON
    {
        public string regKey { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, IList<buttonInfo>> registerButtons { get; set; }
    }
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getAdminPanelJSON>(answer);
```

Строка "regKey" парситься успешно, а вот registredButtons почему-то null

Вот мой JSON:

```
{
"regKey": "admin/admin :)",
"registredButtons": {
    "B1WJxg": [{
        "type": "button",
        "name": "87Z",
        "securityKey": "",
        "buttonID": "",
        "onlyFor": ["sys"]
    }, {
        "type": "button",
        "name": "hjfgh",
        "securityKey": "",
        "buttonID": "",
        "onlyFor": ["1"]
    }],
    "v75wET": [{
        "type": "button",
        "name": "",
        "buttonID": "",
        "securityKey": "",
        "onlyFor": ["me"]
    }]
  }
}
```

Прошу помочь найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней то, что вы пишете, а точней имена свойств. Они должны быть либо идентичны тем, что в JSON, либо помечены атрибутом `JsonProperty` с нужным именем (`[JsonProperty("registredButtons")]` (подсказка вам)).

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=crSNZtlJp6vpjBxIavoi

Comment: А где надо JsonProperty писать?

Comment: @Андрей `А где надо JsonProperty писать?` << над полями класса, которые будут десериализованы